# Kmeans: Between class intertia

Tags: python, clustering, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using KMeans of scikit-learn for clustering of forums.

The attribute inertia_ of model gives the within class inertia but how can i get the between class inertia? In other word how can I verify the quality of my clustering?

Thanks

Comment: I never did much in clustering, but I believe that [Silhouette score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html) is the go-to score for kmeans (more [info here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#silhouette-coefficient), and [example here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Total variance = within-class variance + between-class variance.

i.e. if you compute the total variance once, you can get the between class inertia simply by

```
between-class variance = total variance - within-class variance
```